# Composing impure functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Suppose I have the following impure functions:

```
// Mounts a foo instance into the given dom node
// (this is an implementation detail of the Foo library),
// then returns the foo instance.
const createFoo = (FooConstructor, domNode, options) => {
  return new FooConstructor(domNode, options);
};

const outlineFoo = foo => {
  foo.getCanvas().outline = true;
  return foo;
}
```

If I wanted to use `R.compose` to create the Foo instance and highlight it I could write a function that does:

```
const createFooWithHighlights = (FooConstructor, domNode, options) => {
  return R.compose(
    outlineFoo,
    createFoo
  )(FooConstructor, domNode, options)
}
```

If I wanted to use imperative programming to accomplish the same thing, I would do:

```
const createFooWithHighlights = (FooConstructor, domNode, options) => {
  const foo = createFoo(FooConstructor, domNode, options);
  outlineFoo(foo);
  return foo;
}
```

Whichever one we choose, it would be invoked the same:

```
const highlightedFooInDOM = createFooWithHighlights(Foo, document.body, {})
```

Since all of these functions produce side effects, should I avoid using `R.compose`? Are there rules governing purity and function composition?

Comment: you should read about IO monad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one simplification.  You should be able to write `createFooWithHighlights` more simply as:

```
const createFooWithHighlights = R.compose(outlineFoo, createFoo);
```

Now to the real question:

> Since all of these functions produce side effects, should I avoid using `R.compose`? Are there rules governing purity and function composition?

I would say not.  Functional programming is certainly about reducing side-effects, about shunting them to the edges of your program, perhaps even encapsulating them in patterns and structures (see the comment on the IO Monad, which is certainly good advice, but may be premature.)

But it is not about *eliminating* side-effects.  A program with absolutely no side-effects can do little more than calculate the result of some hard-coded input ... and then not bother to share it with you.

Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) strictly avoids side-effects.  But that's as it should be.  It's a functional utility library; you don't one of those making decisions about how your program interacts with the rest of the world.  Or at least we on the Ramda team do not.  So Ramda functions are pure.  Moreover Ramda is designed to make it easy for you to work in a pure-function manner where practical.

But that does not mean that its functions should *only* be used in creating other pure functions.  When you need to create side-effects, there is no issue at all with bringing in Ramda's tools, especially such an important one as functional composition.

So what you want to do seems perfectly in keeping with normal use of Ramda.

Comment: I'd add that FP is about making side effects explicit and to delay their execution as long as possible (by leaving it to the consumer of a function composition to actually perform the side effects).

Comment: Agreed.  That's what I meant by my somewhat obscure "shunting [side-effects] to the edges of your program" -- either delaying them as late as possible, or getting them (inputs) as early as possible in your flows.